# Remember password automatically on Firefox 12

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

There have been many question with accepted answer on similar topic but none of those deal with newer version of Firefox. So I'm asking how to enable Firefox to remember password automatically on **Firefox 12.0**

Answer (score 2):

Top left firefox button -> Options (click on it, dont go into submenus. A popup will open) -> Security -> Remember passwords for sites (tick the checkbox next to it)

Comment: There's also [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/remember-passwords/) which causes Firefox to ignore the `autocomplete="off"` parameter in many logon forms.